# Is it possible to search for text in iBooks or the Kindle app?

Tags: ipad, search, books, kindle

Is it possible to search for text in iBooks or the Kindle app?  I'm deciding whether to buy electronic copies of some of my reference books, but I would only be purchasing them for the ability to search through the books for specific terms and words.

Comment: This should be two separate question, one for each app

Comment: No. When I tap my screen a row of thumbnails pops up, not that menubar you show.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, in both the iBooks and Kindle apps, you **can** search the full text (excluding text in images) of the book *you are currently reading*.  Here's how to do that in each app:

### iBooks app

While reading a book, tap the screen.  A magnifying glass icon becomes visible in the top right, along with other controls.  Clicking the magnifying glass icon brings up a search box.  After entering your search term in the box, iBooks presents a list of results from the current book, underneath the search box.

[image: image if iBooks search]

### Kindle app

Similarly, while reading a book, tap the screen. At the bottom a magnifying glass icon will become visible.  It works much like the iBooks search feature.

[image: image of Kindle.app search]

### What about searching across all books?

If you wanted to know whether you can enter a search term at the top-level of these apps and have them search across **all** books stored in the app:  **No**, currently neither iBooks nor the Kindle app have such a feature.

However, I have seen this capability on the Kindle device itself – I own a Kindle keyboard model and there is a "search my items" option available that will search all books on the device for a given term.

Answer (score 0):

The search function doesn't work on my ipad with the Kindle app - I've tried it with various books. The magnifying glass appears, but will only allow a search on Google and Wikipedia! There are up and down arrows available, but they are 'dulled and dead'.  On the Kindle the search on the same books works fine.

Comment: It’s a bit confusing, but if you press the [Search] button, it searches the open book, while the buttons labeled “Google” and “Wikipedia” (as you discovered) search the named general services.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing it on an iPad you need wifi I had it not work for me because there was no wifi.

When I tried but with wifi it worked. On a phone I also would suggest being sure there is wifi or data and bars.

This is for the kindle app I don't work with iBooks much.

Comment: sometimes you also have to change how you are searching for a thing in the top bar if you have weird wording or wrong spelling it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Easy. Convert all your Kindle books to epubs using Calibre. Store the epubs in their own folder. Search the directory  at will.