# Is it possible to search within a PDF document using Kindle for iPad?

Tags: ipad, pdf, kindle

I am trying to use the Kindle iPad app as a storage base for all of my PDFs.  But I'm disappointed that I can't seem to find a way to search the text within a PDF using the Kindle iPad App.  Am I missing something?  Seems like a critical, missing feature.

Note that it is possible to [search within a book on both iBooks and Kindle](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/44562/is-it-possible-to-search-for-text-in-ibooks-or-the-kindle-app). This question is specifically about PDF. It is also possible to open these files in Acrobat Reader or OSX Preview, and the text is searchable within those applications.

Comment: @bassplayer7 Actually the majority of PDFs are text searchable.  You're right that _some_ PDFs will be a bitmap scan of a document, this is extremely rare (especially because Adobe Acrobat has the capability to convert scanned text images to actual text).  The PDFs I am referring to can be opened in Acrobat Reader or OSX Preview, and the text is searchable within those applications.  So it's not an issue with the PDFs as they do contain searchable text.

Comment: I see. That would then indeed be a missing feature.

Comment: I'm able to open the same PDFs in the iBooks App and that App has a working Search feature.  So I guess this is just an odd limitation of the Kindle App for iPad :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### No.

As of version 4.5 of the kindle app for IOS in pdf searching is  **not available**.

As of version 1.10.7 of the kindle app for OS X in pdf searching is available.